# how to install the VOGLE graphic library in windows

Tags: c++, windows

I found the VOGLE library described in C.Pozrikidis' book  "introduction to C++ programming and graphics"
http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/CLONE/LIBS/LIBRARY/libvogle/html/index.html
http://www.autochthonous.org/eric/ 
Since I am a beginner, can anyone tell me if it is possible to use it in windows ?
Anyone else using it ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to (cannot) install the library. You can however extract the pre-compiled version of the library from [here](http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/CLONE/LIBS/LIBRARY/libvogle/html/lib.html). Download the tar.gz file under **CYGWIN** section. You should be able to link them to your Windows project and use them.